# Persistent variable Simulink

Tags: matlab, functional-programming, signal-processing, simulink, persistent

I am trying to use persistent variable to store previous samples in an embedded Matlab function. At each step, I get a 32 bit input which I am storing into the persistent variable. As an output of the embedded Matlab function, once all the samples for the simulation time are collected, I am trying to send it to a modulator. The problem is the following: using a random integer generator say for a simulation time of 0.01s, this block generates 626 integers which are then spread to 626x32 bits in an Embedded Matlab function. Now this 626x32 is the input to my current embedded matlab function with persistent variables. The output I expect is (626*32)x1 but the output that I am getting is 626x(626*32) i.e., there are duplicate rows which I want to avoid. Can someone help me with this. This is my code

```
function y = fcn(u)
%#codegen
persistent temp_store;
persistent n;
Tsim = 0.01;
sample_time = 1.6e-5;
no_of_chips = 32;
no_of_samples = round(Tsim/sample_time);

if isempty(n) %%initialize persistent variable
    n = 1;
end

if isempty(temp_store) %%initialize persistent variable
temp_store = zeros(no_of_samples * no_of_chips,1);
end

 %%storing samples into persistent variable
 while(n <= no_of_samples)      
    temp_store((n * no_of_chips)-(no_of_chips - 1): n * no_of_chips) = u;
    n = n + 1;       
 end

 %% After collection of all samples, output the persistent variable
    if(n == no_of_samples + 1)
        y = uint8(temp_store);  

    else
        y = uint8(zeros(no_of_samples * no_of_chips,1));
    end
end
```

Comment: If I run this function in MATLAB I get 20000x1 which is roughly 626x32. How are you getting 626x626x32? what is the size of u?

Comment: I get the same in MATLAB (20000x1) but when i run the same code in my Simulink model in an embedded matlab function, and see the output, I get 626x20000. SIze of u is 636x32

Comment: Well, if your input is 626x32 for each time step, then your output will also be 626x32 for each time step. It looks like the Simulink solver is taking 626 time steps. What solver and time step are you using?

Comment: I am using a sample time of 1.6e-5 and I am using the ode45 solver. However, I get the following warning in the workspace:                                                                                                   '' The model does not have continuous states, hence Simulink is using the solver 'VariableStepDiscrete' instead of solver 'ode45'.''